# Using Subprocess or os.system to run shell commands in python

Tags: python, shell

I need to write a code in Python using functions that a friend of mine developed in shell. Is that possible? Can I do something like

output = subprocess.call('friends_developed_function', shell = True)

Comment: Can you give us more information on what type of code he developed?

Comment: You will need to set `stdout` then read from it because `subrocess.call()` will just return the exit value. You might want to use `subprocess.check_output()` instead.

Comment: What works fine is subprocess.call('script.sh', args)

Comment: It is certainly possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your friend's function is defined before you can call it. You cannot call a function which was defined in a parent process [Note 1]. So you could execute the following:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(
  'source /path/to/function/definition; the_function args if needed',
  shell = True)
```

Note that I changed `subprocess.call` to `subprocess.check_output` so that the call will return the output of the shell function, instead of its exit code.

It's a little awkward fixing the path to the script file with the function definitions. You could instead just define the function directly before calling it, using a string literal:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(
  """my_func() { echo The argument is "$1"; }
     my_func the_argument
  """,
  shell = True)
```

---

#### Notes:

1. Unless you are using `bash`, but that probably won't work for `os.system` or `subprocess.call(..., shell=True)` because those will use the basic shell `/bin/sh`, which often is not bash. Even if you forced the use of bash, and you had properly exported the function definitions, it would still be a bad idea because your python script would only work if the environment were set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of ways to do this, I'm posting what I am familiar with.

```
with open(r"*file location", 'wb', 0) as file:
    subprocess.check_call(*command*, stdout=file)
```

Now the output is in the text file location.I used check_call to validate the command so I assume subprocess.call() just executes the command.

Comment: Why do you assume they want to redirect output to a file?